# Simulate a web server by web.py to accept POST requests similar to that sent from BitBucket repo without having to setup a web hook

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, bitbucket, web.py

I want to simulate a web server by using web.py to accept POST requests similar to that sent from BitBucket repo without having to setup a web hook and by just using a client side  python script.

I have cloned a copy of the  files in a remote repository into two  different folders 
Documents/1_repo  --->  server_script.py, a.txt b.txt 
Documents/2_repo -----> client_script.py , a.txt, b.txt

I added c.txt > Documents/1_rep0 ---> server_script.py ,a.txt b.txt c.txt
I gave a git push and updated my repository in 1_repo
But the 2_repo is one step behind branch Documents/2_repo -->client_script.py, a.txt, b.txt

I have used web.py to create a HTTP server using **server_script.py**

urls = (
    '/(.*)', 'index'
)

class index:

```
def GET(self, name):
    return render.index(name)


def POST(self, name):
    data = web.data()

    parse_POST_response()
    automatic_git_pull()
    return render.index(name)
```

**This is the server side scripting part**. I am able to start a http server waiting for a response from clients side. 
I am confused of how to deal with the client server part.

When i add new file c.txt  on repo_2 i will do a git push to my remote repository. I would like to do all these in the client_script using python requests module using:

```
import request
post_data = # How can i get the POST request on Bitbucket repo without 
               using web hooks and by just using some script on server or client side

post_response = requests.post(url = #BitbucketURL ,data=post_data)
```

When i do  a push on 2_repo the client_side_Script should send a POST message  format like the one below to my server_Script so that the sever can parse the POST response string and make a git pull automatically.

```
{
"canon_url": "https://bitbucket.org",
"commits": [
    {
        "author": "marcus",
        "branch": "master",
        "files": [
            {
                "file": "somefile.py",
                "type": "modified"
            }
        ],
        "message": "Added some more things to somefile.py\n",
        "node": "620ade18607a",
        "parents": [
            "702c70160afc"
```

Can anyone help me on this so that i am able to get the Bitbucket body of POST above and parse it to get the information to a git pull from repository. Any help appreciated. **Advance thanks**

Comment: I've read this a number of times and I can't see what you are trying to achieve. Why do you need a separate "client" script? And why don't you use git hooks, rather than trying to listen to Bitbucket posts?

Comment: @ Daniel Roseman I am trying to simulate a server , so that i can get some specific information of how to parse the POST message returned. I will make use git hooks later but now i want to simulate a client and a server on the same machine to simulate POST response similar to BitBucket POST message